# How to initialize private fields after DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I know you can serialize private fields with DataContractSerializer, but I just want to save a minimum amount of data that is easily human editable. After DataContractSerializer has done its thing is there a function that I can override or set in the DataContractSerializer class that just sets up the private fields after it has done the de-serialization?

```
[DataContract()]
[KnownType(typeof(stateCom))]
[KnownType(typeof(stateIp))]
abstract public  class  state
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string tag;
    [DataMember()]
    public byte Id;

    public HandleConnection master;


    // default data contstructor for xml serialization
    public state()
    {
    }

    public abstract void openPort();


    public abstract void closePort();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create e.g. `OnDeserialized` method in your class and apply [`OnDeserializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) to it like:

```
[DataContract()]
[KnownType(typeof(stateCom))]
[KnownType(typeof(stateIp))]
abstract public  class  state
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string tag;
    [DataMember()]
    public byte Id;

    public HandleConnection master;


    // default data contstructor for xml serialization
    public state()
    {
    }

    public abstract void openPort();


    public abstract void closePort();

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // this is called after deserialization
    }
}
```